# How to statically-link MKL v9.x into a managed C++ DLL to calculate FFT?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I'm coding an application using C# with Visual Studio 2008.  I've been reading the documentation that came with the Intel Math Library...and some forums...but couldn't get an answer.

Here is where I'm at:

**Scenario**:
Attempting to statically-link MKL v9.x into a managed C++ DLL to calculate FFT, using Visual Studio 2008.

Linker command:
/OUT:"C:\Projects\Acquisition Toolkit\Mainline\Builds\Debug\AcquisitionToolkit.FFT.dll" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Projects\Acquisition Toolkit\Mainline\Lib\Win32" /DLL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\Win32\AcquisitionToolkit.FFT.dll.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /ASSEMBLYDEBUG /PDB:"c:\Projects\Acquisition Toolkit\Mainline\Builds\Debug\AcquisitionToolkit.FFT.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE /FIXED:No /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /KEYFILE:"AcquisitionToolkit.snk" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT mkl_c.lib mkl_ia32.lib libguide40.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

Getting an unresolved external when linking:

1>FFT.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100000E) for 'DFTI_DFT_Desc_struct'; image may not run

At run-time, it crashes on the call to DftiCreateDescriptor, presumably because it didn't know the format of the descriptor struct:

// create the FFT descriptor
DFTI_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE desc;
long val = DftiCreateDescriptor(&desc, DFTI_DOUBLE, DFTI_REAL, 1, length);

// commit the FFT descriptor
DftiCommitDescriptor(desc);
We are including the mkl_dfti.h header file.

Are there additional header files we need or additional libraries we need to link with?

Where is that descriptor struct actually defined?

I attempted to dynamically link using the mkl_c_dll.lib, but got the same unresolved external linker warning.

Is there some other linker option I need?

Please if someone could give me some kind of guidance/help. I'd REALLY appreciate it.

Thanks!!

Comment: There is no mkl 9 available on Intel web page any more. I did install the latest 10.2 eval and didn't have any problem in linking it. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-compiling-and-linking-with-microsoft-visual-cc/?wapkw=(mkl+9) You should be just missing some .lib files from C:\Program Files\Intel\MKL\9.x.x\ia32\lib. If I were you, I would just try linking all the lib files in the folder

Comment: I know that mkl9 is out of date, but I'm requested to use it. So I'm not able to install the latest 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only do dynamic linking with c++/clr, i.e. /clr is incompatible with /MT[d]. You need to link to a library compiled with /MD[d] so they use the same runtime. I don't know why it fails when you do dynamic linking but your theory of incorrect descriptor sounds right

Edit: By the way, I don't know if it is an option in your situation but you can use CUDA for doing FFT (cufft) much faster on the GPU.